# linux script to update price

Tags: shell, sed, grep

i would like to do a code that prompts user to input the title and author of a book and i want to use grep to get the data based on just the title and author and echo it back for the user to see and edit the price without having the user to enter the old price

I need help in trying to get the $price Variable just by entering the title and author

```
function update_cost
{
   echo "Title: "
   read title
   echo "Author: "
   read author
   grep -iqs "$title:$author:$price:" BookDB.txt && echo "$title:$author:$price:"
   echo "New Price: "
   read price_r
   sed  -i "/^$title:$author:/ s/$price/$price_r"  BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Price has been    updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the script you wrote?

Comment: Your `grep` command is using `$price`, but you never set that variable.

Comment: So how should i modify it so that i can get that variable i need?

Comment: I suggest using `awk` to print the third column when the first two columns match the title and author.

Comment: Is it possible to show an example?

Comment: just to add on and after i use awk to get the third column how am i going to modify that variable based on a user input e.g third column is called $price and user input is $price_update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to the question above i came up with an answer for that. Hope it Helps

```
 price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
```

I manage to get the 3rd field of what the user input by matching it with the result line followed by using the sed line i edited the third field.

```
function update_cost
{
   echo "Enter Title: "
   read title
   echo "Enter Author: "
   read author
   result=$(grep -ise "$title\:$author" BookDB.txt)
   price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
   grep -iqs "$title:$author:$price:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found!"      
   echo "New Price: "
   read new_price
   sed -i "/^$title:$author:$price:/ s/$price/$new_price/" BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Price has been updated sucessfully!"   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is better suited to extracting a field from the file and assigning it to a variable.

```
function update_cost
{
   echo "Title: "
   read title
   echo "Author: "
   read author
   price=$(awk -F: -v title="$title" -v author="$author" '$1 == title && $2 == author { print $3 }' BookDB.txt)
   echo "Old price is $price"
   echo "New Price: "
   read price_r
   sed  -i "/^$title:$author:/ s/:$price:/:$price_r:/"  BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Price has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Comment: sorry i like to ask what does =$ do? and why -F : -v? not to familiar with awk

Comment: `$(command)` executes the command and substitutes its output; this is basic shell script syntax. `-F:` sets the field delimiter to `:` instead of whitespace in `awk` (it's in the documentation).

Comment: hi, i used the line for price but it did not echo out the old price but instead just went on to the new price

Comment: it shows the successful message but nothing changed

Comment: I left out the filename argument to `awk`. I fixed that, and it works for me now.