# Sed to update title but using the 2nd column author as a matching criteria

Tags: shell, sed, grep

i have this code that is similar to another of my question code but this time i am trying to edit the Title, but using the author as a criteria and leaving duplicates alone. But when i ran the code, it does not work the same as using the title as a matching criteria and editing the author.

i wish to know how should i go about rectifying this. Thanks for the help.

e.g
text file BookDB.txt it contains the following

```
Wolverine:Stan Lee:5:1:1
Wolverine:Stan Tan:1:1:1
```

i want to change the title of Wolverine:Stan Tan to e.g Weapon X. i tried using the code below but it did not work. if i remove /^$author:/ they will change both. so the txt file should be changed to

```
Wolverine:Stan Lee:5:1:1
Weapon X:Stan Tan:1:1:1
```

code

```
  function update_author
{
     echo "Title: "
     read title
     echo "Author: "
     read author
     grep -iqs "$title:$author:" BookDB.txt && echo "Book Found\n"
     echo "New Title: "
     read title_r
     sed -i "/^$author:/ s/$title/$title_r/" BookDB.txt || tee BookDB.txt && echo "Book Author has been updated sucessfully!"
}
```

Comment: consider editing  your question to include small sample data that includes the problem you are trying to solve, your required output format AND what you are currently getting from your script. To my mind this is so close to your other question that it is a duplicate, but if we have some sample data to work with, we can solve your problem once a for all. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux script to update price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852532/linux-script-to-update-price)

Comment: Hi i have included small sample data. Please help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this , first u get the title and match it up with the author to make it unique before doing the switch of the author so that i will not delete every single possible match

```
sed -i "/^$title:$author:/ s/$author/$author_new/" BookDB.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last sed line by

```
Status="$( sum BookDB.txt )"
sed -i "/^\(${author}\):${title}:/ s//\1:${title_r}:/" BookDB.txt
if [ "${Status}" = "$( sum BookDB.txt )" ]
 then
   echo "Book Author has no modification for [${author}:${title}]"
 else
   echo "Book Author has been updated sucessfully for [${author}:${title}] !"
 fi
```

(code is made in a batch mode mind with multiple author/title to change so you could simplify the echo return and method to check any change)

Comment: hi i tried the code but the modification did not take place.

Comment: try, as debug, a sed without -i and redirected to a temporary file, in a second time (if still failing) simplyfy the // by removing the ${title}:. If there is no error, it means that the patterne is not found